# javascript/jquery - hide/show table row if radio buttons checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to js and jQuery.

I have a simple bootstrap table. In two rows, I have radio buttons, one for item 1a and another for item 2a. I have another two rows with classes of price-1 and price-2. I am hiding price-2 initially (class="hidden"), so the only visible row is price-1.

I would like to use js or jQuery to show/hide .price-1 and .price-2 depending on which radio is selected. So, if the radio for Item 1a (id="radioItem1) is selected, I want .price-1 (Item 1 row) to be visible and .price-2 (Item 2 row) hidden. If the radio for Item 2a (id="radioitem2) is selected, I want .price-2 (Item 2 row) to become visible and hide .price-1 (Item 1 row). Only one of them should be visible at a time

Eventually, I will be making the bootstrap table rows clickable, so if someone clicks on the row (not the radio) it will select the radio. Because of this, if possible, I want the js to look if the radios are actually "checked" (not clicked), as I want to remove any possible human error component where a user can accidentally click twice on a row which will essentially toggle a click event twice. I think the on.click function works great for checkboxes, but not necessarily for radios.

How can I accomplish this?

HTML:

```html
<div class="selects-1 col-xs-5">
                               
<select id="licenseRegs" class="form-control selectPCs" name="licenseRegs" style="width: 50%;">
    <option value="5" selected="selected" prodid="43" price="49.99" productname="product1">5 </option>
    <option value="10" prodid="44" price="99.99" productname="product1">10 </option>
    <option value="15" prodid="56" price="149.99" productname="product1">15 </option>
    <option value="20" prodid="68" price="199.99" productname="product1">20 </option>
    <option value="25" prodid="54" price="299.99" productname="product1">25 </option>
    <option value="50" prodid="45" price="599.99" productname="product1">50 </option>
    <option value="75" prodid="62" price="899.99" productname="product1">75 </option>
    <option value="100" prodid="53" price="1199.99" productname="product1">100 </option>
    <option value="125" prodid="78" price="1499.99" productname="product1">125 </option>
  </select>
</div>
                                    
<div class="orderTotal">
  <h4>Order Total:</h4>
<table id="tableOrderTotal" class="table tableTotal">
  <tbody>
      <tr class="rowAnnual">
        <td><label class="active"><input type="radio" id="radioItem1" name="productOptionItem" value="oneYear" checked></label></td>
        <td>Item 1a </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2Annual">
        <td><label><input type="radio" id="radioItem2" name="productOptionItem" value="twoYear" ></label></td>
        <td>Item 2a </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="addItem1">
        <td>Item 1 row</td>
        <td class="price-1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="additem2" class="hidden">
      <td>Item 2 row</td>
      <td class="price-2"><span class="dollars">13</span></td>
      </tr>             
                                                    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle where I am playing with what I am trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/dhs3gphz/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhs3gphz/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pricePerRegUnder = 10;
  var pricePerRegAbove = 12;
  var licenseRegsSelect = $('#licenseRegs');

  function updateTotalPrice() {

    licenseRegs = parseInt(licenseRegsSelect.val(), 10);

    var total;
    if (licenseRegs < 25) {
      total = licenseRegs * pricePerRegUnder;
    } else {
      total = licenseRegs * pricePerRegAbove;
    }

    $('.price-1').html(total);
  }


  licenseRegsSelect.change(function() {
    updateTotalPrice();
  });
$('.rowAnnual').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
  if($(this).find('input').attr('id')=='radioItem1'){
        $('#addItem1').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#addItem2').removeClass().addClass('hidden');
  }
  else{
        $('#addItem1').removeClass().addClass('hidden');
        $('#addItem2').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});

  updateTotalPrice();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandru, this worked perfectly! One last question... I am hiding Item 2a row (id="evergreenRow") if the selection from the dropdown menu is greater than 10. I have this working, however, I need to make the Item 1a radio (id="radioItem1") checked if the evergreenRow (Item 2a row) is hidden. The reason I need this, is to eliminate human error, as someone could select Item 2a row first, then change the dropdown menu selection to more than 10 which will hide Item 2a but the radio for Item 2a will still be checked when it is hidden. I updated my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhs3gphz/8/.